# ajax success status code "200" vs "200 OK"

Tags: ajax, server, http-response-codes

I am facing some issue related to ajax success status code.in local environment ajax success status code return "200" and live website return status code "200 OK"
what is different between both status code.

Comment: How do you read the status code? Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this will help you!

There is no difference between **200** and **200 ok.**

'OK' is just a message with response code 200. In simple term, it is just a success message.

The best part is even you can modify the message(ok) with some interesting message like 'The user has been created.' for the response code 200

Technically, the request was OK and the server was able to respond properly.

Answer (score -1):

Status code and status message are configurable from the back end. I guess your live server is configured to not send a status message

Comment: how to configure server please give me steps.